# JUnit clears instance variable after test

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver, junit4

I have this quite simple test as you can see below, but there is a problem. In the first test "A_login" i navigate to a specific page and get the contents of a table and I store this content in an ArrayList. When the first test is finished i want to use the data i've gathered in the second test but when i try to use it or print the list out it is empty. Is there any good reason why? It seems that JUnit clears the instance variable. How can i make this work?

```
public class Crawl extends Driver {

private static WebDriver driver;
private List<String> table_data;

public Crawl() {
    super();
    this.driver = super.getDriver();
    this.table_data = new ArrayList<String>();
}

/*
    Login and get all open orders
*/
@Test
public void A_login() {
    this.driver.get("http://www.xxxx.no/xxxx/");
    this.driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("Username");
    this.driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Password");
    this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/form/fieldset/div[4]/div/input[2]")).click();
    this.driver.get("http://www.xxxxx.no/xxxx/shops_invoice.php");

    WebElement table = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody"));
    List<WebElement> tr_collection = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for(int i = 0; i < tr_collection.size() ; i++){
        this.table_data.add((tr_collection.get(i).getText());
    }
}

@Test
public void B_getCustomerInfo() {
    System.out.println(this.table_data);
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() { driver.quit(); }

}
```

Comment: You should write your tests so that they're independent of one another.

Comment: Every test case is run on a new instance of the test class. Don't try to optimize your tests the way you want. Simply put the initialization code in @Before method or integrate the tests together in a single test case and make the assertions appropriate so you know what is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how JUnit works. For each test method that it runs, it creates a new instance of the test class, runs the test and throws the test class instance away. This is deliberate: tests should be isolated from one another.

Martin Fowler explained this in more detail here: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/JunitNewInstance.html

Instead of doing what you're trying to do, write a method that fills the table and call it from both tests.

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer that i was looking for! Usually each test are independent but i wanted to see if i could use some of the data gathered in one test to be used in another :)